# Adding custom code to windows application UI

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

In visual studio I can build my windows application, drag and drop buttons etc.

And code is automatically generated and put my `MainForm.Designer.cs` file.

There is a icon `MainForm` in my Solution explorer and it hold all the UI components.

[image]

Question is, how to create custom code myself and access the buttons and components I have created with `drag n drop`. I am unable to create my own files under the `MainForm` icon.

The main Program.cs, where this lays:

```
MainForm form = new MainForm();
Application.Run(form);
```

I can access the form, but I can't access any components. So I had to make all my components form private to public, is that normal?
And everywhere I want to access those, I must pass my `form` variable as parameter.

Is there a nice way to create custom stuff, am I doing things correctly, by getting the form variable from `Program.cs` and then passing it to other classes? Still why the auto generated stuff is tightly coupled under that `MainForm.cs` icon, but I can't add my code inside there.

Comment: an easy way to generate code for something like a button click is to double click on the button in the designer(where you drag and drop), and that will take you to the code that is generated.

Comment: @DROPtableusers I know there that code is, but I can't add my own classes there.

Comment: This is a super basic visual studio question. I think you need to research some tutorials.

Comment: right click on the next level out in the solution explorer, probably on the top level in it and click add and you can choose add a class.

Comment: @DROPtableusers yes ofc I know how to add class, but how can it access my form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your own code to the code behind files, but that code will typically be handlers for user interface events for controls on the form. I think where you're getting hung up is the fact that MainForm is a class, not a project. You add your classes to the project that contains it, then in the event handlers for the form class you would create an instance of whatever class you're trying to access and pass the relevant values from the form to the methods you need to call. This way, your properties can stay private since nothing outside of the form is trying to reach in to access them. While not forbidden, I don't like to pass instances of a Form around as parameters.

Comment: Added code to generated files is not recommended, since you'll lose it all if the files get re-generated.

Comment: Agreed. I meant the code behind file, not the generated file. I'll will edit to clarify.

Comment: Can I also say that, this kind of thing is where `partial classes` are particularly handy. :)

Comment: In VS 2012 WinForms, the code behind for a given Form is a partial class.

Comment: So all my code will be inside single class? Is that how you build a windows app in csharp?

Comment: Only if it is a very small program. :) Think of the code behind file for the MainForm as a jumping off point into the rest of your program. For example, if your program has a File->Open menu item the handler fileOpen_clicked would be in your code behind. It can then instantiate other classes to read and hold the data, etc. Your best bet may be to go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb.aspx and read through the Getting Started with Windows Forms section. This formum is better suited to answering specific questions rather than teaching how to program with a given technology.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio `Design` view, you should have a `Properties` window available. In there, you will see it update every time you select a control in the `Design` view. In the `Properties` panel there is an icon with a lightning bolt with hover text saying `Events`.

If you look through those items that show up and double click on the `Event` that you want to write code for, you will be pushed into code view with code generated to access that `Event`.

But what you shouldn't do is try to run your form from `Program.cs`, the logic tie ins for the code will be generated in the `MainForms.cs`, not the `Program.cs`, and from there, you can access all the properties in a `private` context.

[image]